# how to change header tag in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I get data from a dataservice and I call a XSLT mediator to generate my xml.

My xml looks below.

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP:Body>
        <ADD_STUDENT>
                <name>Joe Average</name>
                <age>21</age>

               <major>Biology</major>

        </ADD_STUDENT>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

But the ADD_STUDENT tag is dependent on some values in a context variable.for one conditon , its ADD_STUDENT , otherwise its CHANGE_STUDENT.

How can i achieve it in WSO2 ESB? I can do two different xslt altogother and call the xslt mediator with a filter. Is there a way to change this tag and append student data as a child ?

Answer (score 0):

After filter condition you can use payload mediator , so in `then` you can frame response like

```
 <ADD_STUDENT>
$1
 </ADD_STUDENT>

where $1 is $body/ADD_STUDENT/*
```

In else condition it should be like

```
<CHANGE_STUDENT>
$1
</CHANGE_STUDENT>
 where $1 is $body/ADD_STUDENT/*
```

Comment: what about soap tags ?
Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Yes you can mention soap tag before using the CHANG_STUDENT tag if you do not want to use payload mediator then try using enrich mediator

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to XSLT. So pass the context value as a parameter to XSLT and then use xsl:if in XSLT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameters in xslt you can do that as follows:

In the xslt mediator call add a property:

```
 <xslt  key="gov:services/jan/transformstuff.xsl" source="/soapenv:Envelope"> 
     <property  name="yourParam" expression="get-property('someProperty')" />
 </xslt>
```

In the xslt you need to declare the parameter using `xsl:param` and then access it using `$paramName` so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="yourParam" />

<xsl:template match="whatever" >
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$yourParam = 'jocket'">
         (do stuff)
```